# How can I solve crash in Xamarin Forms UWP app "The parameter is incorrect."

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin Forms app which works fine on iOS and Android. I am adding UWP support to it, and going through each page fixing issues as I go. I've recently run into a crash on one of my pages which gives me the following stack:

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.

element
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(FrameworkElement obj)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.SwitchRenderer.UpdateOnColor()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.SwitchRenderer.OnControlLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

The crash happens after I push the page that contains switches but I don't know exactly what might be causing it and the error message doesn't give any good information.

How can I diagnose this or fix the problem?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5517

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jason linked, this is a bug in Xamarin Forms 3.6.0.2XXXX

I upgraded to Xamarin Forms 3.6.0.344457 and that solved the problem.